# Pseudo element as separator only between elements on the same line

Tags: css

I'd like to find an elegant solution for the following problem.

I have links separated by pipes, in a responsive layout, here's how they should look depending on the width of the viewport :

On a large screen :

```
link | link | link | link | link
```

on a smaller screen

```
link | link | link
   link | link
```

Notice the pipe separators only appears between the links, not at the beginning or end of a line.

I thought about using a simple :after element to add the | with a :last-child rule to avoid the last item but I'll end up with something like this in case of natural line break :

```
 link | link | link |
     link | link
```

Is there a way to do that in pure css?
Thanks

Comment: you could set pseudo elements, width-specific with @media but to find the exact breakpoint i think is very troublesome

Comment: Only with media queries.   Essentially to do this automagically, you need Javascript as CSS cannot detect wrapping or line-breaks.

Comment: Considering you seem to have set a break-point in your CSS that changes the view of the items, you can simply add a rule in that media query saying you don't/do want a pipe for element X?

Comment: This solution from 2019 might help: https://medium.com/@mandy.michael/you-dont-need-a-media-query-for-that-1-inline-content-separators-a9c562a597a6

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with left-aligning the links when they wrap, you could try something like this:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/mzj8hpb8/1/)

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

li:before {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  left: -.5rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @VXp Unfortunately not

Comment: Yeah I thought about the negative margin and overflow hidden trick, unfortunately it's not working for centered items.